# Fail to connect to camera Service

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I had seen many questions on stack but no one is telling if a Fail to connect to camera service will occur, how to get rid of this `RuntimeException`.

I have an camera application its working fine, I already take care to release the resources but if somehow user install the other application which not releasing the resources properly, my application facing `RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera Service` and hence got crashed, want to avoid this situation.

If i click on original camera application it shows me a `AlertDialog`

```
Camera error: Cannot connect to camera.
```

That's what i exactly want to handle this. I am trying this code to handle it but cant succeed yet.

```
try {
    camera = Camera.open();
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Log.d("Inside RunTime exception", e+"//");
    camera.setErrorCallback(errorCallback);
    reConnectCameraVideo();
} catch(Exception e) {
    finish();
}
```

but camera object returning null on `camera.setErrorCallback` because it wont open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setErrorCallback()` cannot be used for the case where the `Camera` will not open. You appear to be trying to still use the `Camera` -- AFAIK this is impossible until the user reboots their phone if some other app leaked the `Camera`. Simply display your own message to that effect.

Also:

- Use an error logging service, like ACRA, Flurry, BugSense, etc.
- Never blindly finish an activity due to an exception, as in your last `catch` block. Always do something to let the user and/or you (via the error logging service) know about the exception

Comment: yes you are right setErrorCallback() is not working coz camera not opened yet so it still null. Even though i have an idea but didnt test yet create a method that return a boolean and if camera.open() successfully return true otherwise false and at the time of handling this method i can show alertDialog error occured.

Comment: Need suggestion what i can do in case if i got attempt to use camera from different Process. unlock() is not working.

Comment: @PiyushMishra: If another process acquired the `Camera` and has not released it, there is nothing you can do, AFAIK, other than tell the user that the camera is already in use.

Comment: CommonsWare:Thanks for your suggestion will work on it. Actually i have method where i am setting autofocus like camera.autofocus(callback) in my app i have camera as well as mediarecorder also, so when m switching it from camera to mediaRecorder i am releasing the current camera and creating a new for mediaRecorder(only reason to do that the same: attempt to use camera from diff process) and it working fine for me but as i want to set the autofocus again in mediaRecorder facing the same prob attempt to use camera from diff process.